# Python If x==True, and if y==False then start array true

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes.

```
PPASbool=
0   True
1   True
2   False
3   True
4   False

CPASbool=
0   True
1   False
2   False
3   False
4   True
```

I tried this below, but I received an error

```
 File "Typology.py", line 66, in <module>
    if PPASbool==True :
  File "C:\Users\Jim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", 
line 1573, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

if PPASbool==True :
    if CPASbool == False :
        PeerNoCo=True
    else:
        PeerNoCo=False
else:
    PeerNoCo=False
```

I want to put True in a new Array called PeerNoCo if PPASbool is true and CPAS is False.

```
Expected output
PeerNoCo=
0   False
1   True
2   False
3   True
4   False
```

Comment: This is simply a *logical and* with the *bitwise NOT* of one of the series. `a & ~b` if `a` and `b` are the two series.

Comment: The "ambiguous" value error happens when you try to evaluate a series to a signle boolean.  For example if you have a series, A that equals to T, F, T.  A == F is ambiguous, because some of A is False and other parts are True.   On way to add more clarity depending on logic is to use all or any.  if (A == True).all()  or (A == True).any() to return a single True or False.

Comment: Just to add, typically when trying to do logical if else, or if, elif else statements row-wise you would look to `numpy.where` or `numpy.select`, respectively. Though @user3483203 s solution is the most appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. you don't have to say `== True`. If is automatically testing a condition. If you want to condition on variable `temp` being `True`, you can just do `if temp:`
2. You're trying to do a conditional on a series. You can iterate over your values. If you want to maintain indices, you can use `enumerate()`.

EDIT:

As one of your comments have mentioned, the easiest way to achieve what you want is just to store `PPASbool & ~CPAS`.

Comment: I generally agree that `==True` is redundant. However if the dtype is not `bool` (perhaps it was reindexed and now contains `NaN` and is `object`) then it's necessary.